# Set data structure reference

Tags: c++, stl, set

I was asked to create a game using c++, but before I proceed to implement the game I need to research the set data structure from the c++ standard library (STL). I'm looking for a c++ reference that will show how to use this data structure. Also of use would be some information on what it is typically used for, how it works, and what are the pros and cons of using this data structure as opposed to something else.

Comment: First google result for stl set tutorial http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/112676-beginner-c-stl-set-container-tutorial/ Ask a precise question, and show you did some real research

Comment: Here's [one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set). And [another](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/). And [another](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/set.html). Did you have any specific questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A set is a data structure that holds unique items. A set in C++ is implemented with a binary search tree, so you need to have an order on the items (comparison function). You can pass in a comparison function to the constructor, or as a template parameter. Here's a resource to get you started on comparisons: http://fusharblog.com/3-ways-to-define-comparison-functions-in-cpp/

The most important things to do with a set are putting in elements, taking out elements, and checking if an element is already in there. These functions are called `insert`, `delete`, and `find`, respectively, for C++.

To list out all the elements, you need to go through them one by one. The `begin` and `end` iterator functions let you use a `for` loop to access each element one by one.

Here are references for the member functions. They contain examples of use.

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set
- http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/

Answer (score 0):

A google search will reveal a lot of links that will give you a description of the data structure.

Here is a [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/set/) that shows a hands on example; this should get you going...